# CSS: Which is faster for the browser? color:#fff; or color:#ffffff;

Tags: css, optimization

First things first, yes I know the render the same color, my question is is a simple query about speed.

This is just a topic of interest regarding optimising page load speeds, but which of the options in the title will render faster (even if it is the tiniest difference)?

My thought process is that with the shorthand version (#fff) the browser will be tasked with assuming the rest of the hex-dec is fff. On the other side the longhand version might take longer or less time because of the extra explicit characters.

I figured someone might be able to shed some light on the topic.

Comment: I don't see anything on the web with this as a benchmark. You could probably run one fairly easily using jsfiddle.net or just a static html page

Comment: I'd say there are more important things to optimize than this. Also the answer may probably depend on a the browser implementation.

Comment: I think the difference would be so tiny it wouldn't effect much, the only note i can chip in is that if you used the full name and had alot off color your css file would in theory be larger so would take more time to load.

Comment: Many will probably repeat this, but this optimization is useless except the fact that the data over network will be 3 bytes less in favor of #fff. Otherwise, in regards to rendering - you won't put a dent in changing the rendering speed.

Comment: thanks for the input everybody, just a minor topic of interest in page loading optimisation :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#fff` is fewer characters, which is generally better. Network latency and bandwidth matter more than processing time in most cases. For this reason, most CSS compressors will intelligently optimize to the `#fff` version. The network matters more than parsing speed in this case.

If you're concerned about parsing time, I doubt the difference between the 2 declarations accounts for even 0.005% of total parsing time. There are much bigger bottlenecks that dwarf any speed difference compared to parsing color declarations.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the implementation.  One browser could take 100 times longer for the long version, and another browser would be the other way around.

Write your code so that it's readable, meaning easy to change going forward.  If you want fast CSS consider using [yui-compressor](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor).