# How to convert and match the background color RGB(255, 255, 255) with #fff using Selenium TestNG and Java

Tags: java, css, selenium, testng, assertion

In my automated code, trying to match background color of a web-element 'Find the best card for me' text.

**Console view :**

[image]

To do it, I have to identify that web-element on page first, get the color, store in String as expected value.

Below code does the same:

```
WebElement slickDotButton2Presence = driver.findElement(homepageobjectsloc.slickDotButton2);
slickDotButton2Presence.click();
String findTheBestCarsForMeTextBackgroundColour = driver.findElement(homepageobjectsloc.secondBannerFindTheBestCardForMeText).getCssValue("background");
```

In website value is in hex, but Selenium method will return values in rgb So whatever value I got from above line of code need to convert into hex first and then have to compare with assert method.

Used below line of code:

```
try {
    String value = findTheBestCarsForMeTextBackgroundColour.trim();
    String[] rgbs = value.split("\\)")[0].split("\\(")[1].split(",");
    long r = Long.parseLong(rgbs[0]);
    long g = Long.parseLong(rgbs[1]);
    long b = Long.parseLong(rgbs[2]);
    String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x", r, g, b);
    System.out.println("=> The hex conversion is : " + hex);
    Assert.assertEquals("#fff", hex);
}
```

But when I execute it , getting below error:

```
=> The hex conversion is : #ffff
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [#ffff] but found [#fff]
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
    at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:513)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEqualsImpl(Assert.java:135)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:116)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:190)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:200)
    at tests.homepage.HomePageStepDefinitions.verify_that_Find_the_best_card_for_me_text_is_available_on_the_second_banner_in_hompage_then_click_on_it(HomePageStepDefinitions.java:795)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

How to convert onto hex and make test pass?

Comment: Think a moment about this: `String.format("#%02x%02x", r, g, b)`

Answer (score 2):

Try selenium library

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.Color;
String value = findTheBestCarsForMeTextBackgroundColour.trim();
String hex = Color.fromString(value).asHex();
System.out.println("=> The hex conversion is : " + hex);
Assert.assertEquals("#fff", hex);
```

You can refer selenium official documentation [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/db1c2add0b47d845b7d0d7d67b65cee92d9bb323/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/support/ColorTest.java)

Below is the test case in selenium junit tests written for your case. Make sure the rgb String you are passing in `Color.fromString("rgbString")` should be in format the function expects.

```
  @Test
  public void rgbToHex() {
    String hex = "#01ff03";
    String rgb = "rgb(1, 255, 3)";
    assertThat(Color.fromString(rgb).asHex()).isEqualTo(hex);
  }
```

Comment: Getting this error --------

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.openqa.selenium.support.Colors.RGB(255, 255, 255) NONE REPEAT SCROLL 0% 0% / AUTO PADDING-BOX BORDER-BOX

Comment: @Avinmita - Please check the new answer and also check official junit tests for this case.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

From your code trials, presumably you are getting back:

- r -> **`255`**
- g -> **`255`**
- b -> **`255`**

---

### Console view

As per the Console view you are seeing: **`#fff`**. @DanHerbert in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536473/css-which-is-faster-for-the-browser-colorfff-or-colorffffff) mentions, it is the [css](/questions/tagged/css) compressors that will intelligently convert `#ffffff` to `#fff` for optimizing *page-loading speed* as *network latency*, *bandwidth* and *parsing time* matters more than processing time in general.

To deal with these cases, @T.J.Crowder in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767206/how-to-convert-ffffff-to-fff-or-fff-to-ffffff-for-assertion) suggests to look for a string starting with `#` followed by three pairs of matching hex digits, and replace them with just the short form before you consider for assertion as follows:

```
static String getHex(int r, int g, int b) {
    return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b).replaceAll("^#([a-fA-F])\\1([a-fA-F])\\2([a-fA-F])\\3$", "#$1$2$3");
}
```

Sample implementation:

- Code Block:

  ```
  package demo;

  public class Background_White {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.out.println(getHex(255, 255, 255)); // #fff
      }

      static String getHex(int r, int g, int b) {
          return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b).replaceAll("^#([a-fA-F])\\1([a-fA-F])\\2([a-fA-F])\\3$", "#$1$2$3");
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  #fff
  ```

In your usecase you can use it as:

```
try {
    String value = findTheBestCarsForMeTextBackgroundColour.trim();
    String[] rgbs = value.split("\\)")[0].split("\\(")[1].split(",");
    long r = Long.parseLong(rgbs[0]);
    long g = Long.parseLong(rgbs[1]);
    long b = Long.parseLong(rgbs[2]);
    String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b).replaceAll("^#([a-fA-F])\\1([a-fA-F])\\2([a-fA-F])\\3$", "#$1$2$3");
    System.out.println("=> The hex conversion is : " + hex);
    Assert.assertEquals("#fff", hex);
}
```